# Action Item Register - Can a formal method of tracking action items be successfully applied to teams using more adhoc / agile methods?

Tags: team-management, planning, process, tasks, tracking

**Background**

I am a software developer working on an Action Item Register Application.  Based on research I found a process flow chart that helped clarify a way of processing action items.

I want to ask if it is possible to apply a flow as shown below to shorter term projects that require less time to complete action items.   If the action item cycle time is relatively short will this type of process be effective generally.

**Question**

Can a process that is similar to the flow below be applicable to teams that require cycle of creating action items to closing items to be short in terms of a week or several days?

Image courtesy of:
[help.newforma.com/Video/Nuggets/Newforma Project Center - Action Items Process Flow.png](http://help.newforma.com/Video/Nuggets/Newforma%20Project%20Center%20-%20Action%20Items%20Process%20Flow.png)

[image: Process Flow Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google up on Kanban task boards. You'll find that they are very similar.

Agile backlogs and their task boards are essentially an action item register. It's not the tool that makes agile work so well, it's the team and the collaboration of the the team.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I appreciate it.  I am thinking that this method of tracking might be a bit too much, unless I remove some steps or fields to make it more appropriate for the context.   I did in fact recently come across Kanban task boards which seems remarkably similar and clear.   I also found the Cumulative Flow Diagram (CFD) mentioned on this network to be a good graphical representation of tasks completed.

Comment: Kanban can be as simple or complex as needed. You might also Google "Just In Time", "Flow Chain Analysis" and "Value Chain Analysis".